# Nested for loop and if condition pandas replacement

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested, runtime

I have two different pandas data frames where in the first data frame (price), I have two columns. The first column named value has some values in it and the second column amount has the available amount for each price. The second data frame (bins) has as index some price intervals which are produced from the price data frame. For each row of the price data frame I check each row of the value column to find the interval that it belongs from the bins data frame and if the value is in an interval I assign the available amount in the bins data frame. If another value is again in the same interval I sum up these amounts in the group_bins data frame.

```py
import pandas as pd

bins = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 16, 20, 3, 9, 11, 35, 12, 54, 33, 3, 22, 23]
})

price = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [2, 5, 7, 8, 16, 20, 3, 9, 11, 2.5, 3.4],
    'amount': [50, 112, 130, 157, 146, 148, 300, 124, 151, 100, 32]
})

bins['bins'] = pd.qcut(bins['value'], 12)
group_bins = bins.groupby(['bins']).sum()
group_bins['amount'] = 0
del group_bins['value']

for j in range(price.shape[0]):
    for i in range(group_bins.shape[0]):
        if price.loc[j, 'value'] in group_bins.index[i]:
            group_bins.loc[group_bins.index[i], 'amount'] += price.loc[j, 'amount']

            break
```

Expected Result:

```py
                 amount
bins                    
(0.999, 2.333]        50
(2.333, 3.0]         400
(3.0, 5.0]           144
(5.0, 7.333]         130
(7.333, 8.667]       157
(8.667, 11.0]        275
(11.0, 13.333]         0
(13.333, 18.667]     146
(18.667, 22.0]       148
(22.0, 26.333]         0
(26.333, 34.333]       0
(34.333, 54.0]         0
```

My problem is that I have 100k data and all this process takes too long to finish. 
Is there any elegant and much faster way to replace these nested for loops and the if condition?

The expected result is the final column in the group_bins amount column. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO, have a read of [ask] and if possible - post some sample data (in a textual format just like your code) and your expected output.

Comment: Problem solved thanks to Graipher. <https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232238/nested-for-loop-and-if-condition-pandas-replacement/232240#232240>

Answer (score 0):

If you use `for` loop on a dataframe, you are doing it wrong 99% of the times. Try this instead:

```
bins = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 16, 20, 3, 9, 11, 35, 12, 54, 33, 3, 22, 23]
})
bins['bins'] = pd.qcut(bins['value'], 12)

price = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [2, 5, 7, 8, 16, 20, 3, 9, 11],
    'amount': [50, 112, 130, 157, 146, 148, 300, 124, 151]
})

price.merge(bins, how='left', on='value') \
    .groupby('bins') \
    .agg({'amount': 'sum'})
```

Result:

```
                  amount
bins                    
(0.999, 2.333]        50
(2.333, 3.0]         600
(3.0, 5.0]           112
(5.0, 7.333]         130
(7.333, 8.667]       157
(8.667, 11.0]        275
(11.0, 13.333]         0
(13.333, 18.667]     146
(18.667, 22.0]       148
(22.0, 26.333]         0
(26.333, 34.333]       0
(34.333, 54.0]         0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I want to create the bins based on a larger value range. I updated also the expected results that I expect to have.